# SSAS Caching of Cube schema

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

Whenever i browse a SSAS cube for the first time after full processing ,it takes a lot of time to open.When I ran the Profile trace,  i found that there was an EvenSubClass 'MDSCHEMA_MEASURES' with the below XMLA which was executed .

```
<RestrictionList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
          <CUBE_NAME>Customer Cube</CUBE_NAME>
        </RestrictionList>

<PropertyList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
          <Catalog>OLAP_PRD</Catalog>
          <LocaleIdentifier>7177</LocaleIdentifier>
          <Content>SchemaData</Content>
          <Format>Tabular</Format>
        </PropertyList>
```

After this command was issued,all the measures were loaded into SSAS Cache which took 10 minutes to execute.

Can we have this Schema data be permanently stored in the cache and not be flushed out anytime by SSAS ?

Comment: Can you monitor this in Profiler connected to SSAS? Turn on all Execute MDX Script XXXX events and let us know which ones have long durations. Then copy the slow statements into your question. Maybe some parts can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I enabled the Execute MDX Script events and found that Static sets in the Cube were evaluated when the cube was browsed . It looks like SSAS caches the returned results .

Comment: yes. Sets are evaluated and cached upon the first connection by a user. If multiple users have the same security in roles it should reuse that cache for both users. So what are you going to do? Remove the sets? Or do you need help optimizing them?

Comment: @GregGalloway : There is a Set defined like this  "  TAIL(FILTER([Play Date].[Date].[Date], [Measures].[Win Amount] > 0), 1) " . This seems to be getting all Dates where the Win Amount >0 and then finding the last date. Can you please help me fine tune it.

Comment: Try the following. create member CurrentCube.[Measures].[Win Amount Not 0] as IIf([Measures].[Win Amount]>0,1,Null),Visible=0;
create set CurrentCube.[Your Set] as TAIL(NONEMPTY([Play Date].[Date].[Date], [Measures].[Win Amount Not 0]), 1);

Comment: If that isn't fast enough, then you either need to build aggregations. Or better yet just add a new Is Most Recent Win Date flag to your Play Date dimension using SQL calculations.

Comment: @GregGalloway : I used NonEmpty and seems it is working well. Additionally, can you please let me know if w can change these static sets to dynamic sets as they are very rarely used sets. Will dynamic sets be evaluated when you open the cube for browsing ?

Comment: Sort of. It will get evaluated with the WHERE clause of any queries that use it (so will return different results). But it also gets evaluated when field lists are built in Excel. See http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2014/02/18/when-dynamic-sets-are-not-dynamic.aspx

Comment: if I have answered your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. You might also up vote any comments you think others might find helpful in the future.